# Retrieving & storing access_token with Passport

Tags: express, passport.js, openid

I'm using [PassportJS](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) along with [`openid-client`](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) and [`cookie-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) in my Express server for authentication. I'm using `openid-client`'s ["Usage with Passport"](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client#usage-with-passport) as a starting point, and I'm currently able to authenticate successfully. Since I need an access token for APIs that are proxied through my server, I chose to save the access token in my user session with this bit of code:

```
passport.use(
  'oidc',
  new Strategy(
    { client, params, passReqToCallback, sessionKey, usePKCE },
    (req, tokenset, userinfo, done) => {
      logger.info('Retrieved tokenset & userinfo');
      // Attach tokens to the stored userinfo.
      userinfo.tokenset = tokenset;
      return done(null, userinfo);
    }
  )
);
```

My next step is to get and store a new access token. Part of the information that comes with `tokenset` is the `expires_at` key, and it's set to expire in one hour. So of course, if it's close to expiring or has expired, I want to get a new token.

The documentation says to use:

```
client.refresh(refreshToken) // => Promise
  .then(function (tokenSet) {
    console.log('refreshed and validated tokens %j', tokenSet);
    console.log('refreshed id_token claims %j', tokenSet.claims);
});
```

Okay, I understand that and I have that bit of code working as well. But I have no idea how to save it back into my user session. If I make a subsequent API call that's proxied through my server, I'll still have the old token in `req.session.passport.user.tokenset.access_token`. So how do I update that?

(I probably should put as a caveat I'm still very new to OpenID / Oauth authentication as well as Passport itself, so some of what I'm doing may be completely obvious.)